# How do I build C# asp.net ajax wizard (or rather convert a PlaceHolder based wizard)

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, ajax, wizard

I have looked at similar questions and cant seem to get the answer I need.

We have a Webform based asp.net application with Wizard based interfaces. These vary between 2 to 5 steps where each step may be reliant on the previous one, ie populated before the user sees it. The Wizards are based on hiding and showing PlaceHolder controls for each step. This works well as the visible property can be set on postback, the validators work accordingly and there is full control over the steps.

Converting this to an "ajax" style wizard by wrapping the page with an UpdatePanel doesnt seem to work since the non-visible parts are not rendered initially causing all sorts of javascript/jQuery issues when hiding and showing PlaceHolders. I suspect I may be incorrect in the way I am constructing things making it difficult to ask the right questions.

Rather than trying to fix this mess, How would you guys go about converting this Wizard type interface. I have only used the UpdatePanel part of the MS ajax libaray and am somewhat familiar with jQuery.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your problem will solved adding property value for asp:updatePanel ChildrenAsTriggers=true.

If not, and errors pop up still try changing style of controls that have to be invisible to `display: none` 
When you set it like that they exists but they aren't visible.

And the last suggestion is this tutorial from link:
http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/06/quick_ajax_tip_provide_a_bette.html

Comment: -ChildrenAsTriggers="true" is set to true.

-Are you saying that I should stick a the concept where everything is rendered all the time, just shown/hidden on the client using css/jQuery?

-Thanks for the link, will have a look.

Comment: If you have reference from ajax extender on control, that control has to be rendered as same as ajax extender. If it's not rendered at same time it produces Java Script errors.